# Toda vez que eu carrego arquivos obtenho uma quantidade grande de erros

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

Preciso de ajuda.

Toda vez que carrego qualquer arquivo no Visual Studio 2015 obtenho uma quantidade imensa de erros gerais.

Estou começando a desenvolver para windows phone e logo ao importar o primeiro sample, baixado da msdn obtenho uma quantidade consideravel de erros:

[image: erros]

Vale ressaltar que os erros que ocorrem não ocorreram em um computador da universidade em que curso, visto que foram abertos diversos samples nos computadores de lá.
Durante o periodo em que eu tive aulas sobre isso, meu professor simplesmente desmarcou ou marcou alguma opção em alguma checkbox e pronto, sumiram todos os erros.

Gostaria de saber como fazer para resolver esta dor de cabeça que me impede de importar arquivos!

Comment: Jovem, que "sample" é esse que você está tentando importar? Como você está tentando importar? Clique em [edit] e coloque o código do "sample" e como você está fazendo para importar na sua pergunta

Comment: Amigo, vou me explicar melhor:

Comment: Estou desenvolvendo aplicativos para windows 10 (windows phone, desktop e tudo mais da UWP). Quando crio um aplicativo e compilo ele, não obtenho nenhum erro na janela que indica qualquer possível erro. Como parte do meu desenvolvimento, eu procuro abrir diversos exemplos de aplicativos que são disponibilizados na MSDN. Durante o curso que fazia, o professor abria os mesmo exemplos e conseguia compilar e rodar naturalmente, porém aqui em casa é só eu carregar estes arquivos que obtenho inúmeros erros. Por exemplo: carreguei um exemplo de NFC e recebi 400 erros

Answer (score -2):

Tudo indica que o "Sample" que vc está tendando abrir foi feito em ASPNET 4 MVC 5, e vc está criando um projeto ASPNET 5 MVC 6.

Crie um novo projeto, mas como ASPNET MVC 5 (e não ASPNET 5 ou vNext) e faça a importação.